# Very big file when AVAudioFile encoding raw PCM to AAC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using `AVAudioFile.write` to convert a raw PCM data buffer into an `aac` file. However, the file is too big - about 3KB/s (i.e. 30s audio costs ~90KB). Notice that, if I use `AVAudioRecorder` with the same config, I get about 2KB/s (30s audio costs ~60KB). I have tried a lot of settings but none works. I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

The encoder code:

```
func encodePcmToAny(buf: AVAudioPCMBuffer, outputPath: String, formatId: AudioFormatID) throws {
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(formatId),
            AVSampleRateKey: buf.format.sampleRate,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
// --- I have tried all the following without ANY change! ---
            //AVEncoderBitRateKey: 16000,
            //AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey: 16000,
            //AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue,
            //AVEncoderBitRateStrategyKey: AVAudioBitRateStrategy_Variable,
            //AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey: 8,
            ] as [String : Any]
        
        let file = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath), settings: settings, commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, interleaved: false)
        
        try file.write(from: buf)
    }
```

Comment: Need to look at code where you create `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.  Now it's look like you are trying to convert whole file with one buffer.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes I firstly create a big avaudiopcmbuffer by file.read(). It is because, I need to decode aac into pcm, then concat two files, then encode back into aac.So it is a bad way? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you doesn't have enough operation memory for that.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Er... Sorry I do not quite understand it... My sound is about 30s so with 16000 sample rate and float32 it is <2MB. Even if with 5min audio it is <20MB of pcm . IMHO 20MB memory is acceptable. So which memory do you mean is not enough? Thanks!